# apache AccessFileName .htaccess error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am setting up a new installation of a LAMP using a different method than I have before.  After adding some virtual hosts I attempted to reload apache and received an error.

```
Syntax error on line 160 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
  ...fail!
```

The error.log presents nothing in the way of new information.  This is the block of text

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

The line beginning with 'Order allow' is the offending command but I do not know how to fix it.  Research points to similar errors returned for syntax problems but I can't find an identical one for the way this syntax is supposed to be.  Can anyone offer help?

**2013-12-28 Update**

I followed the advice of Tuga and added

```
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

to httpd.conf.  Now I receive the error:

Cannot load /etc/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so into server: /etc/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Doing some more research I came across

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
</pre>
```

to load in a php file and view in a browser.  According to the script `mod_authz_host` is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see such information in your apache error log: `Invalid command 'order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

It means you have to add additional module to your `httpd.conf` (or equivalent file). Module can be loaded by adding such line (sometimes you just have to uncomment this line in configuration file):
`LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so`

If you compile apache by yourself you have to enable `--enable-authz-host` (which usually is enabled by default)

[source](http://thrull.com/corner/webserver/apache-module-mod-authz-groupfile/)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am totally lost.  The "Invalid command..." appeared in terminal.  The error.log was of no help for details.  I don't know what module to add.  From steps I executed in [this how-to](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) the apache2.conf was generated by the install.  I am not compiling by myself.  That is a little above my skills level.

Comment: open httpd.conf and uncomment this line ' LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so' . if you cannot find it just add that line to the apache config (httpd.conf). restart apache and you're good to go.

Comment: search for the modules (`mod_authz_host.so`, etc.) on your disk and change the path accordingly.